# Spring, Hibernate database query

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to build simple spring security hibernate login app. But I have a problem geting result from Database with hibernate. 
Here's my Service class that will query.

UserAccountService:

```
package main.java.services;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import main.java.model.UserAccount;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("userAccountService")
@Transactional
public class UserAccountService {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager){ 
            this. entityManager = entityManager; 
        }
    public UserAccount get(Integer id)
    {
        String sql = "FROM UserAccount as ua WHERE ua.id="+id;
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
        return (UserAccount) query.getSingleResult();
    }

    public UserAccount get(String username)
    {   
        String sql = "FROM UserAccount WHERE username='"+username+"'";
        System.out.println("test1");
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("test2");
        System.out.println(query.getSingleResult());
        return (UserAccount) query.getSingleResult();
    }

    public void add(UserAccount userAccount)
    {
        entityManager.persist(userAccount);
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the code will reach "test1", but it won't reach "test2" and it won't show me any errors. I have tried with native query and I will get a hibernate awnser to console then, but still no result to my return ( gives 0, but should return me a UserAccount object). With native query console show's me this "Hibernate: FROM user_account WHERE username='something'"
Here's my conf file for database:

HibernateContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}"
          p:user="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}"
          p:acquireIncrement="5"
          p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
          p:maxPoolSize="100"
          p:maxStatements="50"
          p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="hibernatePersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
                <property name="databasePlatform">
                    <value>${jdbc.dialect}</value>
                </property>
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If execution gets to line `x` but not line `x+2` then line `x+1` must be raising an exception, blocking/looping indefinitely, forcibly terminating the thread, or calling a vm exit routine.

Of these, the most likely is that it raises an exception. If you don't see an error, you probably have code that's swallowing the exception, like:

```
try {
    ...
} catch {
    // Ignore exception
}
```

Either that, or it's likely getting logged somewhere and you're not looking at the logs. Check your application server logs for details. You didn't mention what app server you're using so I can't be more specific about that.

If you can't identify the issue that way, attach a debugger to your application (yes, this works when your app is running in a container/appserver). Set a breakpoint at the last known OK statement then step through the code watching what happens.

Comment: adding try catch block did show me my error "UserAccount is not mapped [FROM UserAccount ua WHERE ua.username = :username]", not sure how to fix that error now tho :D